# Add hyperlink IN the hover text

Tags: html, css

So, I have an image and when hovered on it, some text appears. What I want to do is to add a hyperlink in that text.

For example: Text says "hello my name is" then i want to include "click to find out" as a hyperlink linking to another page in my web application.

I have already tried the below:

```
<span>hello my name is <a href:"abc.php">click to find out</a></span>
```

The above is replacing the entire `<span>`by just showing "click to find out" as a hyperlink.

Any suggestions please ??

code tried:

```
<span class="text-img">
            Diversity index is measured on a scale of 0 to 100.
            Higher number indicates a greater degree of relative diversity.<a target="_blank" href="PanelHow.php">test</a>
            </span>
```

Comment: What have you tried?, share that code

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: ` <a href:"abc.php">` should be `<a href="abc.php">`. Just a typo you missed or you have it in your code like this.

Comment: Inside `<a>` add span example: <a href=""><span></span></a>

Comment: `I have an image and when hovered on it, some text appears` can you share the code which is doing the same.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I already added the coded in the update version @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: @SuperUser tried that too, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared the actual code, it is difficult to find out the exact problem. So i have developed the small example for you. Check the below code and it is working fine.

```css
.test {
  display:none;
}
.maindiv {
  display:inline-block;
}
.maindiv:hover .test {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
   <img src="http://miumosa.com/assets/products/sample-_20170209104115.png" width="100" />
<span class="test">hello my name is <a href="abc.php">click to find out</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't hover text, instead just the part which is hyperlinked

Comment: reproduce your issue in snippet/fiddle, otherwise difficult to help.